# arabic tinymce doesn`t working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, tinymce

i have downloaded arabic language package and editor show in arabic format but when i right some it`s not write with right direction it`s always start with left direction and arabic language always start with right direction but this is not working..

my code --

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/tiny/tinymce/js/tinymce/tinymce.min.js"></script>
<body>
<textarea name="name"></textarea>
</body>
</html>

<script type="text/javascript">
       tinymce.init({
            language : "ar_SA", // arabic
            mode : "textareas",
            selector: "textarea",
            theme: "modern",
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [**documentation**](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration:directionality), you may do that :

```
tinymce.init({
    // ...
    directionality : 'rtl', // Right To Left
    // ...
});
```